# Scikit Learn DecisionTreeRegressor algorithm not consistent

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree, mse

I am currently using decision trees (using Scikit Learn DecisionTreeRegressor) to fit Regression tree. The problem I'm facing is that using the algorithm with same data as 6 months ago there is a slight change in output (ie. the optimal split point). My guess is that it could be that they have changed slightly the way they compute the mse criterion or something like that. Anybody knows?

Answer (score 2):

`DecisionTreeRegressor` exhibits random behavior unless you specify a `random_state` as an argument of the constructor.

The details of `random_state` from [`the documentation`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) explains the spots where randomness might affect your execution - see specially the bold part I highlighted:

> random_state int, RandomState instance or None, default=None
>
> Controls the randomness of the estimator. The features are always randomly permuted at each split, even if splitter is set to "best". When `max_features < n_features`, the algorithm will select max_features at random at each split before finding the best split among them. But the best found split may vary across different runs, even if `max_features=n_features`. That is the case, if the improvement of the criterion is identical for several splits and one split has to be selected at random. **To obtain a deterministic behaviour during fitting, `random_state` has to be fixed to an integer**. See Glossary for details.

Comment: Thanks for the random_state idea which I didn't know. Yet, the small changes in the splits that I got from my previous runs (6 months ago) don't seem related to the random_state parameter because I am now getting the exact same results  having tried many random_state values. It seems to me that some more fundamental change in the way the optimal split is calculated. Maybe they now calculate children mse by dividing with n-1 instead of n where n is the size of the sub-sample (ie. correct for degrees of freedom)?